# How to train a Neural Network to give me a classified output based on male or female?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

In my project I have two vectors of [200x1] that should be used in Neural Network and trained in a way that it gives me the subject's fingerprint gender.

I think I should provide a target vector based on the subject's gender from the ground truth data (like 1 for female and 0 for male) But I am not sure if this consideration is correct.

Any idea for this?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Then how I can give two input vectors to train?

Comment: actually your input is the 200x1 and the output has 2 nodes. y=1, y=0.

Comment: yeah but as I mentioned, I have two vector of 200x1. How is it possible to give two input vector in this case

Comment: just merge two vectors and put it as input. You just need to know for each element the corresponding output. So using indexing you can shuffle the two vectors into one vector and give it to the NN as the input (e.g. input size = 400x1) and get two vectors as output.

Comment: perfect. Let me see how it goes then

Answer (score 0):

it sounds right. actually you are training a classification to classify two groups male and female.

Your input is two vectors each has size **200x1** and the output should have **2** nodes. **y=1**[male], **y=0**[female].

So, just merge two vectors into one vector and put it as input. You just need to know for each element in the input vector the corresponding output value (i.e. either **1** or **0**). So using indexing you can shuffle the two vectors into one vector and give it to the NN as the input vector (e.g. input size = **400x1**) and get two vectors as output.

So you can also use the same input output set to try with the SVM algorithm alongside to test the result. It is provided in MATLAB and the usage is pretty easy.

example:

```
v1 = rand(1,200);   % I am setting these values as random, but you should use the values you know
v2 = rand(1,200);
input = [v1 v2]';
y = randi(2,400,1)-1; % make a random vector including 0 and 1 for female and male (you should use your data)

net = newff(...)    % or whatever NN you are using
net = train(net,input,y) % train the NN using the data
```

Comment: How about the number of hidden nodes? Can it be same default 10?